# How to close pdfs after only using PDFMergerUtility?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, pdf, tesseract

My problem is that i merge a bunch of pdfs into one and after thats done, i cant delete the pdf files i created the merged one from. 
The following code sample is the part in question.

```
//combine PDF files into one
        PDFMergerUtility merger = new PDFMergerUtility();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            merger.addSource(new File(outputPath[i] + ".pdf"));     
        }
        merger.setDestinationFileName("C:\\Users\\kh\\Desktop\\work\\OCR\\images\\finalPDF\\"+ file.getName().split(Pattern.quote("."))[0] +".pdf");
        merger.mergeDocuments(null);

        System.out.println("Third step done.");
        FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File(pdfPath));
```

It compiles without error, it runs but at `FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File(pdfPath));` it gives this error:
 `java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: C:\Users\kh\Desktop\work\OCR\images\tempPDF\splitTiff9.pdf`
I figured that PDFMergeUtility doesnt let go of the pdfs in questions, but i have no clue how to solve this. BTW closing the running application releases the pdfs and can be deleted.

Update:

```
PDDocument[] pdfStreams = new PDDocument[n];
                PDFMergerUtility merger = new PDFMergerUtility();
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    File f = new File(outputPath[i] + ".pdf");
                    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(f);
                    merger.addSource(f);        
                    pdfStreams[i] = doc;
                }
                merger.setDestinationFileName("C:\\Users\\kh\\Desktop\\work\\OCR\\images\\finalPDF\\"+ file.getName().split(Pattern.quote("."))[0] +".pdf");
                merger.mergeDocuments(null);

                //close pdfmerger´s streams
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    pdfStreams[i].close();
                }`
```

i call the array before for loops and i try to close between merging and deleting everything in the folder. Gives ssame error as before

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working application code.I have made some modification.it's working.

```
            File file1 = new File("D:\\Files\\a.pdf");
            File file2 = new File("D:\\Files\\b.pdf");

            try {
                PDDocument doc1 = PDDocument.load(file1);
                PDDocument doc2 = PDDocument.load(file2);
                PDFMergerUtility PDFmerger = new PDFMergerUtility();
                PDFmerger.setDestinationFileName("D:/merged.pdf");
                PDFmerger.addSource(file1);
                PDFmerger.addSource(file2);
                PDFmerger.mergeDocuments();
                System.out.println("Documents merged");
                doc1.close();
                doc2.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Third step done.");
            FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File("D:\\Files"));
```

POM Dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: ye as i was searching the web i found pdfdocument.close too but why do ihave to cast it into it if it works without? i guess for close function

Comment: if you do not close then stream remain open so it is not able to delete.

Comment: Well this is nice and probably works for you but my update doesnt